# How to specify delegate or event handler in xml markup of user control (not in code behind)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls

I tried playing around with the XML mark up but couldn't get it to work. It would be nice if I can define my own call back delegate in my user control, which the containing page will set, and my user control subsequently call back to. Typically this is done in the .CS file of the containing page, and that's done.

But when I try setting the delegate in the XML markup, it's not working as i want. For example:

In my Default.aspx I want to embed MyUserContro.ascx which looks like this

```
public delegate void NotifyDel(string msg);
public NotifyDel OnNotify{set;get;}
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArg e){
   Notify?.Invoke();
}
```

In my default.aspx markup, i would like something like this instead of doing it in the .CS code behind:

```
<uc1:MyUserControl runat="server" OnNotify="MyHandler" />
```

I am getting some error about unable to convert to delegate from string representation or something to that effect.

Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if the code sample you've provided is 100% correct but the following should work:

**User Control code:**

```
public delegate void NotifyDel(string msg);

public event NotifyDel Notify;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Notify?.Invoke("msg");
}
```

**Default markup:**

```
<uc1:MyUserControl runat="server" id="MyUserControl" OnNotify="MyUserControl_Notify" />
```

**Default code:**

```
protected void MyUserControl_Notify(string msg)
{
    // ...
}
```